# New-Alias in script fails, ok interactively

Tags: powershell

I've been using this simple little script for the past couple of years:

```
#! PowerShell
# Create utility aliases for working with fax account management cmdlets
# account searches
new-alias -name gfad                        -value '.\Get-FaxAcctByDNIS.ps1'            
new-alias -name gfap                        -value '.\Get-FaxAcctByPhone.ps1'           
new-alias -name gfasql                      -value '.\Get-FaxAcctBySQL.ps1'             
new-alias -name gfasso                      -value '.\Get-FaxAcctBySSO.ps1'             
new-alias -name Get-AcctByDNIS              -value '.\Get-FaxAcctByDNIS.ps1'            
new-alias -name Get-AcctByPhone             -value '.\Get-FaxAcctByPhone.ps1'           
new-alias -name Get-AcctBySQL               -value '.\Get-FaxAcctBySQL.ps1'             
new-alias -name Get-AcctBySSO               -value '.\Get-FaxAcctBySSO.ps1'             
# route searches
new-alias -name gfra                        -value '.\Get-FaxRouteByDestination.ps1'    
new-alias -name gfrd                        -value '.\Get-FaxRouteByDNIS.ps1'           
new-alias -name gfrsql                      -value '.\Get-FaxRouteBySQL.ps1'            
new-alias -name Get-RouteBySQL              -value '.\Get-FaxRouteBySQL.ps1'            
new-alias -name Get-RouteByDestination      -value '.\Get-FaxRouteByDestination.ps1'    
new-alias -name Get-RouteByDNIS             -value '.\Get-FaxRouteByDNIS.ps1'           
new-alias -name Get-RouteBy                 -value '.\Get-FaxRouteBy.ps1'               
new-alias -name Get-RouteBySQL              -value '.\Get-FaxRouteBy.ps1'               
# user searches
new-alias -name gfun                        -value '.\Get-UserByName.ps1'               
new-alias -name gfusso                      -value '.\Get-UserBySSO.ps1'                
new-alias -name gfusql                      -value '.\Get-UserBySQL.ps1'                
new-alias -name Get-FaxUserByName           -value '.\Get-UserByName.ps1'               
new-alias -name Get-FaxUserBySSO            -value '.\Get-UserBySSO.ps1'                
new-alias -name Get-FaxUserBySQL            -value '.\Get-UserBySQL.ps1'                
# miscellaneous
#EoF#
```

Hard to imagine much going wrong with that (unless you run it twice and get "already defined" errors), right?
And it always has worked just as it should.

Suddenly this morning I invoke it then try to use one of the aliases and I get this:

```
12:07:19|32|~\docs\rts\geafax# .\xyzzy.ps1 new-alias : The alias is not allowed, because an alias with the name 'Get-RouteBySQL' already exists. At C:\Users\200018252\docs\rts\geafax\xyzzy.ps1:23 char:1
+ new-alias -name Get-RouteBySQL              -value '.\Get-FaxRouteBy. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (Get-RouteBySQL:String) [New-Alias], SessionStateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AliasAlreadyExists,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewAliasCommand​​​
```

BUT... the alias is NOT already defined:

```
12:07:29|33|~\docs\rts\geafax# gal get-routebysql
gal : This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the name 'get-routebysql' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ gal get-routebysql
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-routebysql:String) [Get-Alias], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAliasCommand
12:07:56|34|~\docs\rts\geafax# gci alias:\get-routebysql
gci : Cannot find path 'get-routebysql' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ gci alias:\get-routebysql
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-routebysql:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

​​​Nor have ANY of the other aliases defined in the script been created. Which makes it odd that it didn't throw an error until it got all the way down to Get-RouteBySQL before complaining!

To make it all the more mysterious, I can execute all the lines from the script directly from the CLI prompt and they all succeed!

I've made NO changes to the script or to my Powershell environment.

I'm completely stumped. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You could add a `-Force` to your `New-Alias` commands, which would over-write them, if the script thinks they exist.

Comment: They're definitely not in the output of `gal`?

Comment: Thanks, Zoredache. I'd thought about -force but would really like to understand what is going on and why.

Comment: They are definitely not in the output from Get-Alias (gal)

Comment: Curioser & curiouser... added -force, per Zoredache. Now it throws no errors but still doesn't create the aliases!

Answer (score 0):

Run your script *dot-sourced*. Read [About_Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) help topic:

> **`.` Dot sourcing operator**
>
> Runs a script in the current scope so that any functions, aliases, and
>   variables that the script creates are added to the current scope.
>
> ⊕ Note
>
> The dot sourcing operator is followed by a space. Use the space to
>   distinguish the dot from the dot (`.`) symbol that represents the
>   current directory.

**Example**:

```
D:\PShell> powershell -NoProfile -NoLogo
PS D:\PShell> Get-Alias -Name foo*
PS D:\PShell> Get-Content -Path D:\PShell\SU\1149083.ps1
```

> ```
> new-alias -name foobar  -value 'Get-Culture'
> new-alias -name foo-bar -value 'Get-Location'
> new-alias -name foo-bar -value 'Get-Random'   -Force
> ```

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SU\1149083.ps1
PS D:\PShell> Get-Alias -Name foo*
PS D:\PShell> . D:\PShell\SU\1149083.ps1  # dot-sourced
PS D:\PShell> Get-Alias -Name foo*
```

> ```
> CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
> -----------     ----                                               -------    ------
> Alias           foobar -> Get-Culture
> Alias           foo-bar
> ```

```
PS D:\PShell> foo-bar -Minimum 0 -Maximum 99
```

> ```
> 41
> ```

Read [Get-Alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-alias?view=powershell-3.0) and [About_Aliases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-3.0) help topics as well:

> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, **`Get-Alias`** displays
>   non-hyphenated alias names in an 
> `<alias> -> <definition>` format
>   to make it even easier to find the information that you need.
>   
>   …
>   
>   The arrow-based alias name format is not used for aliases that include
>   a hyphen. These are likely to be preferred substitute names for
>   cmdlets and functions, instead of typical abbreviations or nicknames,
>   and the author might not want them to be as evident.